# How to permanently correct syntax highlighting after "?>"?

Tags: vim, php, syntax-highlighting

In Vim, I have a PHP script that contains a line similar to the following:

```
$return = "<?xml attributes=\"values\" ?>";
```

Normally, the `?>` characters will close an opening `<?php` tag, however the `?>` is in quotes and does not close the opening `<?php` tag in this script; however, Vim's syntax highlighting switches from PHP to HTML after the `?>`.

Is there a way I can fix this behaviour permanently? I know that in Vim I can do `:syntax sync fromstart` to fix the problem, however when I close and re-open the document, the syntax highlighting goes back to being incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in Vim 7.4, and I do not see the behavior you're seeing with PHP highlighting.

As a stop-gap, you can "fool" Vim's highlight rules by changing the PHP:

```
$return = "<?xml attributes=\"values\" ?" . ">";
```

Yes, it's basically a kluge, but it works.

Comment: That's bizarre. I'm using vim 7.4 as well, and my example works just fine, however the original file is still broken. Let me do some more analysis...

Comment: This actually appears to be a bug in vim! This happens only when the file is first opened and if the `<?php` tag is above what you see when you first open the file. Try adding a bunch of blank lines and experimenting. If you test this and verify this happens to you as well, I'll send a bug report. Also, your solution still fixes this.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it.